# Parse fetch in Backbone Model

Tags: backbone.js, model, fetch

I am trying to store the response into an array, right now the response is an object and I would like to parse the response's array (userBookList) in the Model. I'm not exactly sure how to do it, below is my code:

```
this.books = new Backbone.Model();
this.books.fetch({
    async: false,
    url: user.get('booklist').href
});
```

I know I can just set `this.books = this.books.get('userBookList')` but that seems too hacky. What needs to go in the first line to parse? I've tried the parse function, but it's never called. Sorry, I've never used fetch.

Comment: Why are you using a model if you just want to grab an array from the server? Why not use a straight `$.ajax` call? Or why don't you use a collection to wrap the array? What does the response look like and what do you expect to get out of it?

Comment: @muistooshort I'm just practicing the use of fetch. I'm trying to shorten the code as much as possible and really don't need a collection of the information. It's a typical response:
userBookList would be in attributes, it contains an array [0:"book1",1:"book2", etc...]

Comment: Wouldn't you create your own model (`M = Backbone.Model.extend(...)`) and throw a `parse` implementation in there then?

Comment: Since `fetch` works asynchronously, you'll have to "wait" until its finished. you can do it by simply using `success` callback within `fetch`, or on the other hand using an event listener, listening to the model `change` => `this.books.on("change, function() { ... });`. then you can process the response as you wish...